# composer autoload provider with extra not working in laravel package?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i want to create a laravel application

i follow youtube videos about auto load sereice provider in composer.json

For the convenience of the user
imean load serveiceproviders without user know about it

i put configs in packages composer.json but composer extra not working 
why?!

Comment: Put your code so we can see what's wrong: `composer.json` & also `config/app.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laravel application or package?

if you want create a laravel package using composer (with autoload providers)

you need upload your package to packagist and install it for test provider autoload

> in local (laravelProject/packages/someName/packageName/)
>
> need add your package namespase to laravelProject psr-4 autoload